# Windows 10 factory reset continues to fail. Now a Bigger Issue

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash, system-restore, reset

So long story short, my boyfriend's computer is an acer with windows 10 installed. As of late it has been running excruciatingly slow, and after many failed attempts to find and fix the performance issues, he decided it would be best to just factory reset and remove everything. Both of us have done this before to different computers with no issue, but his laptop is proving to be a challenge.

**The Problem:** 
Trying to reset it failed every time we tried, I have tried all of the suggestions I could find online to force it to reset and get around the failure message. Last night I tried one last time, by going through and uninstalling everything manually and then starting the factory reset process. It seemed to work, made it to at least 50% before we went to bed (took about 8 hours to get there) and at some point during the night the computer crashed.

NOW when we try to start the computer, it gives a blue screen and says Your laptop has crashed and needs a repair tool.

**The Question:**
***What can I do to fix this new problem? AND still reset the darn thing.***

It WAS a perfectly functional computer, a few years old, but was working perfectly until a few weeks ago. All virus scans came back clean, except avast which would crash before it could complete the scan. I greatly appreciate any help anyone has to offer.

Comment: Wipe clean and install from scratch.

Comment: At this point you should be suspect of the hdd. Sadly if hats the case your current system state cannot be repaired.  Get a new hdd and reinstall Windows

Comment: @DavidPostill That was the entire point of the question. Thats the goal, but it keeps failing.

Comment: @Ramhound I was afraid of that, is there a way to tell if it is definitely the hdd?

Comment: @evan10593 A reset is not the same thing as installing from scratch.

Comment: In support of @DavidPostill, see [How to do a Clean Install of Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/).

Comment: @DavidPostill true, but the issue remains that currently we are stuck with a blue screen. And I can't even wipe the computer if I can't boot it.

Comment: @harrymc thank you, I'll look into that page.

Comment: @evan10593 You boot from the install media and wipe the existing disk as part of the install. See the link harrymc posted.

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you for the help! I had already tried the media creation tool twice a few days ago, but it failed to create the drive for some reason. I'm trying again now, and hopefully it'll work and I can get my boyfriend's computer working again. He's completely given up on the thing at this point.